# Powershell -Match operator not respecting regex expression, by designed or bug

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to use -match operator to match string that start with a lowercase.

**But**

```
"ABC" -match "^[a-z]" //return true
```

I know there is a version of `-cmatch` that will using case sensitive match.
But since I am forcing it to start with lowercase , isn't it suppose to work even I use `- match`?

Is this a bug on Powershell?
Or is it by designed that `-match` will not respecting the case no mater what?

If it is by desgined , why?

Comment: it is by design. the most common use of `-match` in PoSh scripting is to match _broadly_, not _narrowly_. so ... that is why there are default case-insensitive operators AND specialty operators that are _explicitly_ case aware.

Comment: nice design, I think python should learn from Powershell and change their Zen, `In the face of ambiguity, always guess.`

Comment: it's a useful default for the uses that the designers of PoSh saw being used. [*grin*] just as regex has an 'ignore case' option, PoSh has options to 'NOT ignore case'. ///// plus, if you use the dotnet `[regex]` stuff, you can get a more common regex behavior.

Comment: You are not forcing anything. If you use `"(?-i)^[a-z]"`, then you are forcing case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It's by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-6); for the reasoning, you'll have to ask Microsoft.

Comment: Nice design, now I have to forget all I have learned from Regex and learn Powershell Only.

Answer (score 5):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0).

> **By default, all comparison operators are case-insensitive.** To make a comparison operator case-sensitive, precede the operator name with a `c`.

Emphasis mine.

To make a regular expression match case-sensitive you can either use the case-sensitive match operator (`-cmatch`):

```
'ABC' -cmatch '^[a-z]'   # evaluates to $false
```

or add a [miscellaneous construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/miscellaneous-constructs-in-regular-expressions) with the option to disable case-insensitive matching to your expression, as [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53713478/powershell-match-operator-not-respecting-regex-expression-by-designed-or-bug#comment94282491_53713478) suggested:

```
'ABC' -match '(?-i)^[a-z]'   # evaluates to $false
```

Regular expression options in miscellaneous constructs take precedence over the default behavior of operators.